# Scripted HP printer configuration changes

Tags: windows, configuration, command-line-interface, scripting, printer

I've got about a dozen Windows XP machines that I need to make a couple specific printer configuration changes to. The printer is local "virtual" printer connected to a program for an electronic document delivery service. I'd like to not have to visit each machine individually. I already have the means to execute commands remotely on the machines, I just can't seem to find away to adjust these settings via command line or script.

Specifically I need to be able to make the following changes:

### 1. As an admin user:

- **Device Settings** -> **Font Substitution Table**

  - Change from "Courier New" to "Courier"

### 2. As a specific* user:

- **Printer Preferences** -> **Paper/Quality** -> **Advanced** -> **Graphic/Print Quality**

  - Change to "600 x 600"
- **Document Options** -> **Printer Features** -> **Graphics Mode**

  - Change to "HP-GL/2"

**This change is a per user configuration, unless there's some way to make it once. In this situation I only really need it for a specific (different) user on each machine.*

Comment: Might be a good time to visit setting up a print server. That way you could make all the changes via the print server and not each computer individually. As an alternative, you could also correct this with the UNC of each of your PCs, so you wouldn't need to visit them each physically. Just click on the Print Sharing.

Comment: @Nixphoe: the printer is local and part of a program on the machine. You print to it and the program runs to continue with the process. It can't be networked so print server wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These kind of settings are dependent on the printer driver, the configuration of which varies according to the manufacturer.

Your best bet is to speak to the manufacturer and see if they have any way to configure this (some do, some don't)